# Razor syntax error "Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, razor-2

I m declaring the following syntax in MVC Razor view:

```
 @{
    foreach (var speaker in Model)
    {
       speaker.Name;               
    }           
 }
```

and getting error

> Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

I am able to correct by adding a `@` with `speaker.Name;`

but why it is ? I m sorry, I'm new to Razor but while I'm in code block `@ {}` why I am required to use @ again. Even I m not mixing it with HTML ?

Help please.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Without the `@`, the razor engine interprets `speaker.Name;` as pure C#—that is, simply referencing a property, but not doing anything with it—but that won't compile. *A statement which simply references a property by itself, without getting or setting its value, is not valid in C#.*

Consider this razor

```
@foreach (var speaker in Model)
{
   var name = speaker.Name;
   @name
}
```

The first line is pure C#. It declares a variable, `name` and initializes it with the value of `speaker.Name`.

The second line is interpreted as a razor print directive, which prints the value of `name` in the output.

Comment: thanks, but I am already in code block @{}, ofcourse it is pure C#

Comment: @haansi A statement which simply references a property by itself, without getting or setting its value, is not valid in C#.

Answer (score 4):

In a Razor code block, `@` means *print this value out*. In this particular case, without the `@` you are not telling Razor to do anything, you are simply inserting a property name in place of a statement.

This is why the `@` will correct in this case. It has a different meaning than "mark a code block".

As a side note, you can also use `@` to mark a literal block:

```
@:speaker.Name;
```

would also "correct" it, by printing out, literally "speaker.Name;" instead of its value